# Padding for a file containing Russian Cyrillic characters in a file not working - one Russian character is counted as 2 bytes

Tags: unix, cyrillic

I am trying to create a file with fixed column lengths in Unix. The file contains Russian Cyrillic characters and those characters are interpreted different from the normal 1-byte characters.

I am using below script to modify the file (the delimiter of the columns is @-@ and the row delimiter is \r\n):

```
input_file=$1
output_file=$2

awk -F '@-@' '{printf("%-200s%-200s%-200s%-200s%-200s%-200s%-200s%-200s\r\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)}' $input_file > $output_file
```

For the columns with normal characters, the output file contains correctly 200 characters columns, but for a column with 30 Cyrillic characters, the output column contains only 170 characters. This way, the lines in the file won't have the same length because the Cyrillic characters occupy 2 bytes and the code will interpret the bytes and not the characters.

Example: НИКОЛАЕВНА has 10 characters, but the script calculates it as having 20 because it occupies 20 bytes.

One input file example:

```
НИКОЛАЕВНА@-@russ@-@12345@-@asklle@-@НИКОЛАЕВНА@-@454@-@111@-@asdfg
```

Can you please suggest a way to create the padding so that all the rows have the same number of characters?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe awk can do this, but gawk should handle this by default as long as your locale isn't set to "C". For example, `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` should provide the expected behavior using gawk.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `gawk` character based string function `substr`, to trim your strings.
The standard `gawk` `printf` width formatting function is character based. check if you are using the latest `gawk`.

To trim all your fields to 200 characters:

```
for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) $i = substr($i,1,200);
```

So your script should be:

```
awk -F '@-@' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=substr($i,1,200);printf("%-200s%-200s%-200s%-200s%-200s%-200s%-200s%-200s\r\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)}' $input_file > $output_file
```

Or more concise:

#### script.awk

```
{
    for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        $i = substr($i,1,200);
        printf("%-200s", $i);
    }
    print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, the problem is not the fact that the width exceeds 200 characters, but the fact that the columns don't reach the maximum width (200 in this case) because the Russian characters are interpreted as 2 bytes, so the rows with these kinds of characters will remain with a shorter length. So in this case I think there is no need to trim them because it would have no effect, I need the exact opposite - to make one Russian character count as 1 byte instead of 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `awk` script:

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {FS="@-@"; # field separator is '@-@'
    h="          "; # length(h) = 10
    h=h h h h h h h h h h; # length(h) = 100
    h=h h; # length(h) = 200
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        #length is character based function
        head = substr(h,1,(length(h)-length($i))); # cut alignment head to the correct length
        printf("%s%s", head, $i); # output the current aligned field
    }
    print;
}
```